# Range offset error when taking screenshot

Tags: cypress, screenshot

I try to take a screenshot with:

```
cy.visit('https://www.mypage.com/')
cy.screenshot()
```

But I get the error:

```
RangeError: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 6497276. Received 6497280
```

Does not found anything about the screenshot offset on SO.

Comment: Might be: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2034

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user "first last" I found the solution.

You have to set the viewport before, like:

```
cy.viewport(1280, 720)
cy.screenshot()
```